# Trying to save a file on an android system and make it downloadable by the user

Tags: android, android-studio

I am sorry I am extremely new to android and I am lost.  I successfully found out how to save a file on an android system, but every time I try  to search for the file on my Android phone (which is where I have a copy of this app located)  I am unable to locate it.  I know it is there because the app would not start up with out it.  How do you write a file that can be both used by the App AND searched by the user in the File Explorer.  I am using a Galaxy Note 3 Android version 5.0  Any help would be appreciated.

```
private void WriteFile(String FileName, String FileCont, boolean isAppend){
    File file = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/" +  FileName);

    try {
        FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file, isAppend);
        stream.write(FileCont.getBytes());
        stream.close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex){

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did set the permissions to write on external space in your manifest.xml?

For reference see

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

You have to set the "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" permission to write on external disk. Just add the following line to your android manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

It will implicitly contain the permission to read external storage as well ;).

Comment: I am able to both save and read a file from my application, my problem is that once the file is written I can't see it in the stock Android file explorer from the UI.

Comment: Were did you search? In the application directory or your home directory?
The url
getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/" +  FileName
is in your application storage.

Comment: I looked in Android > data >  and could not even find the application folder.